# Pass argument from qlineedit

Tags: python, pyqt, subprocess, sys

I want to pass the text from the `QLineEdit` to the next function.
I want `person_name` to receive the text i entered in `QLineEdit`. 
I tried using the function `add_function(self,people_folder,shape)`, but when I declared in main at final it says that self is not defined.

What should I do, to make it work for `person_name` to receive the text I entered in the `QlineEdit`?

Comment: what is `people_folder` and `shape`

Comment: `people_folder == PEOPLE_FOLDER` ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to instead of

```
def add_person(people_folder, shape):
    person_name= (sys.argv[0])
```

adding `self` parameter to `add_person` method and calling `text()` from `self.lineEdit` instead of `sys.argv[0]`

```
def add_person(self, people_folder, shape):
    person_name = self.lineEdit.text()
```

---

> when i declared in main at final it says that self is not defined.

this is due to self is referencing to Object (created Class), you are not supposed to add self in method `add_person(self,PEOPLE_FOLDER, SHAPE)` when calling it. It's added automatically when called, but you need to call from created Object, like

```
myCamera = camera()
myCamera.add_person(PEOPLE_FOLDER, SHAPE)
```